# Set environment variable during push for GitHub Actions

Tags: git, environment-variables, github-actions, git-push

In GitLab CI I can set environment variables at `push`-time [using `-o` flag](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/push_options.html#push-options-for-gitlab-cicd):

```bash
git push -o ci.variable="MAX_RETRIES=10" -o ci.variable="MAX_TIME=600"
```

How can I do a similar thing for GitHub Actions?

Comment: I don't think you can, you can see what's available in the push event [here](https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#push) and [push options](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt--oltoptiongt) don't seem to be included.

Comment: @jonrsharpe; No. It's not about environemnt variables.

Comment: Title (and question has "Set environment variable ....."  and then you claim the question is not about environment variables ?   Please explain....

Comment: If you actually read the answer, though, it does tell you the same thing I did: push options aren't exposed. What specific thing you want to do with them is irrelevant.